# Need to reduce memory usage when using pd.concat() on multiple df's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, file-io

I need to read in multiple large .csv's (20k rows x 6k columns) and store them in a dataframe.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe) has excellent examples that have worked for me in the past with smaller files.

Such as:

```
pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,index_col='Unnamed: 0') for f in file_list))
```

Other more direct approaches that I have attempted is:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in file_list:
    print(file_)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=0)
    list_.append(df)
df = pd.concat(list_)
```

However all the solutions revolve around creating a list of all the csv files as individual df's and then using `pd.concat()` at the end over all of the df's.

As far as I can tell it's this approach which is causing a memory error when concat'ing ~20 of these df's.

- **How could I get past this and perhaps append each df as I go?**

Example of file_list:

```
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_26.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_30.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_25.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_19.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_27.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_18.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_28.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_23.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_06_03.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_24.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_29.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_06_04.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_20.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_22.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_06_06.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_06_05.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_06_01.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_06_02.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_31.csv
/realtimedata/orderbooks/bitfinex/btcusd/bitfinex_btcusd_orderbook_2018_05_21.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSVs are still manageably sized, so I would assume the issue is with misaligned headers.

I'd recommend reading in your DataFrames without any header, so concatenation is aligned.

```
list_ = []
for file_ in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=0, skiprows=1, header=None)
    list_.append(df)

df = pd.concat(list_)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did work for ~80% of those files, but failed again concatenating the entire file list. Is it completely unreasonable for this to blow up memory? I will continue to debug and check each file.

Comment: Split them in half and read in half the files each into a separate df,, consumed 14GB on a 16GB machine and would not concat :(